# can not use "(" in awk command

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk

I tried following awk command in my Linux box, it throws error.

```
awk -F "VALUES(" '{print $2}'
```

**Error :**

```
awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /VALUES(/
```

I also tried with back slash, its also not working.

`awk -F "VALUES\(" '{print $2}'`

**Error :**

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `(' 
awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /VALUES(/
```

Please let me know how to include ( in awk search string.

Comment: Yes.  What was your question?

Comment: try `awk "VALUES\(" '{print $2}'`

Comment: @JorgeCampos it won't work. see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if the value of `-F` is longer than 1, it was considered as regex, so you need do something like:

### regex character class:

```
kent$  echo "a foo( b"|awk -F"foo[(]" '{print $1,$2}'
a   b
```

### escape the `(`

if you really want to escape the `(`, you need:

```
kent$  echo "a foo( b"|awk -F"foo\\\\(" '{print $1,$2}'
a   b
```

or

```
kent$  echo "a foo( b"|awk -F'foo\\(' '{print $1,$2}'  
a   b
```

Comment: @logan in this case I prefer `[(]` or re-think the `FS` e.g. default space, then check the previous column `=="VALUES("` etc... any way, important is it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Linux, so you're likely using `gawk`.  From the gawk man page on my system:

```
   -F fs
   --field-separator fs
          Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS prede-
          fined variable).
```

and:

> ### Fields
>
> > As each input record is read, gawk splits the record into fields, using
> >        the value of the FS variable as the field separator.  If FS is a single
> >        character,  fields  are separated by that character.  If FS is the null
> >        string, then each individual character becomes a separate field.   **Otherwise, FS is expected to be a full regular expression.**

Since you've got multiple characters in your `-F`, it's being interpreted as a regular expression.  And you have an opening bracket without a closing bracket.

You may be able solve this either by escaping the bracket (`"VALUES\("`), or by putting the bracket in a group (`"VALUES[(]"`).  I recommend the latter, because escaping things with backslashes can be ugly and unpredictable, and will help point out to you that this is a regex, not a string, when you re-read this script a few months from now.